# Monitoring API calls in Mac OSX

Tags: macos, api, monitor

I am beginner on mac and I am doing some reverse engineering and want to know which APIs are called from the executable. 
In windows some applications do this such as [apimonitor](http://www.rohitab.com/apimonitor/)

is there any solution in MAC?

Comment: Please refer : https://superuser.com/questions/42813/looking-for-http-debugging-proxy-for-mac-similar-to-fiddler-on-windows
Please refer: https://superuser.com/questions/42813/looking-for-http-debugging-proxy-for-mac-similar-to-fiddler-on-windows

Comment: This is a great question.  Did you ever find anything?